# Best way to remove header and footer for a particular page in YII

Tags: php, html, css, layout, yii

I came across a situation where I don't need to show the `header` (it has the navigator bar and logo)`and`footer` for a particular page in yii. There are a number of tweaks to do this. For example, having a check for a particular action where the layout will not load header and footer..

Does yii provide any thing solid for this issue?

Do we have anything like `$this->layout->unsetHeader();?` or `$this->layout->unsetFooter();?`

I don't want to have a check in the layout file to sort this out.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can set $this->layout to false;

```
$this->layout = false
$this->render('view', $data);
```

This can also be achieved using renderpartial

```
$this->renderPartial('view', $data);
```

The approach above will display a page segment and not other items of the page layout (for example inclusion of javascript and css, and HTML headers).

If you want your layout files to have logic in it, you can pass variables from the controller.

```
$this->layout = 'mytheme';
$this->show_css = true;
$this->render('view', $data);
```

and in your layout

```
<html>
<body>
   <?php if ($this->show_css) { ?>
   <div id="menu">
     <ul><li>Menu Option 1</li><li>Menu Option 2</li></ul>
   </div>
   <?php } <?
   <div id="body">
      <?php echo $this->content; ?>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to use a variable in the controller. use a global variable instead.

```
   Yii::app()->params['show_menu'] = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't find function like you looking for.

I think the best and siplest way is however use a proper layout, and call it in controller in this way

```
public function actionYourView()
   {

    $this->layout='yourLayout';
    $this->render('yourView');
}
```

In this way you don't need check inside the layout for header and footer the logic is all in the controller. And assign the proper layout is easy.